# Spaces and backslashes in Visual Studio build events

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build

I have an application that is supposed to aid my project in terms of pre- and post-build event handling. I'm using ndesk.options for command line argument parsing. Which gave me weird results when my project path contains spaces. I thought this was the fault of ndesk.options but I guess my own application is to blame. I call my application as a post-built event like so:

```
build.exe --in="$(ProjectDir)" --out="c:\out\"
```

A simple foreach over args[] displays the following:

```
--in=c:\my project" --out=c:\out"
```

What happened is that the last " in each parameter was treated as if it was escaped. Thus the trailing backslash was removed. And the whole thing is treated as a single argument.

Now I thought I was being smart by simply escaping the first " as well, like so:

```
build.exe --in=\"$(ProjectDir)" --out=\"c:\out\"
```

In that case the resulting args[] look like this:

```
--path="c:\my
project"
--out="c:\out"
```

The trailing backslash in the parameters is still swallowed and the first parameter is now split up.

Passing this args[] to ndesk.options will then yield wrong results.

How should the right command line look so that the correct elements end up in the correct args[] slots? Alternatively, how is one supposed to parse command line arguments like these with or without ndesk.options? Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to escape the last backslash?

```
build.exe --in="$(ProjectDir)\" --out="c:\out\\"
```

This works probably only, as long as the `ProjectDir` ends in `\`, which should be [given](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(VS.80).aspx).
*This is just an idea, but I did not give it a try*

**EDIT:**
I found a [comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/mwade/archive/2006/09/22/Finally_2E002E002E00_-Real-Content.aspx) which suggests to leave out the trailing `"`

Comment: That, indeed, works like a charm. And here I thought I tried every combination. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I actually used "." to solve this same problem:

```
build.exe --in="$(ProjectDir)." --out="c:\out\."
```

primarily because otherwise it might look like you are trying to escape the second quote...which you're not, you're escaping the final \ (which is hidden).
I also added a REM in the postbuild command describing why I did that.